# Adding column values row by row based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe with some `Score`. Now, I like to check for each `Name`, if the `Score` improved.

If the `Score` for `Name` did improve, I'd like to write `1` - otherwise `0`. If there is no previous `Score` available for a `Name`, I'd like to write `NaN`

So my dataframe looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    first = {
        'Date':['2013-02-28','2013-03-29','2013-05-29','2013-06-29','2013-02-27','2013-04-30','2013-01-20'],
        'Name':['Felix','Felix','Felix','Felix','Peter','Peter','Paul'],
        'Score':['10','12','13','11','14','14','9']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(first)
```

And the result should look like this:

```
second = {
        'Date':['2013-02-28','2013-03-29','2013-05-29','2013-02-27','2013-04-30','2013-01-20'],
        'Name':['Felix','Felix','Felix','Peter','Peter','Paul'],
        'Score':['10','12','11','14','14','9'],
        'Improvement':['NaN','1','0','NaN','0','NaN']}

result = pd.DataFrame(second)
```

I considered doing something like:

```
df1['Improvement'] = np.NaN
col_idx =  df1.columns.get_loc('Improvement')
grouped = df1[df1['ID'].isin(['Felix', 'Peter','Paul'])].groupby(['ID'])
for name, group in grouped:
    first = True
    for index, row in group.iterrows(): ...
```

But I actually have more than 100 names within the column `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be simplified, but you can break it out into a groupby to get a dummy column with NaN values for the first name's score that appears, then do some np.where for the logic you want

```
df['v'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Score'].shift()
df['Score'] = pd.np.where(df['Score'] > df['v'], 1, 0)
df['Score'] = pd.np.where(df['v'].isna(), pd.np.nan, df['Score'])

print(df.iloc[:, :-1])

         Date   Name  Score   
0  2013-02-28  Felix    NaN  
1  2013-03-29  Felix    1.0   
2  2013-05-29  Felix    1.0   
3  2013-06-29  Felix    0.0   
4  2013-02-27  Peter    NaN  
5  2013-04-30  Peter    0.0   
6  2013-01-20   Paul    NaN
```